# How do I access knowledge article version in the Global Search Results Component

Tags: lightning, community, custom, component

How do I access knowledge article version in the Global Search Results Component like the default layout shows?

[image: How do I access knowledge article version in the Global Search Results Component like the default layout shows?]

Answer (score 1):

You should select Knowledge. 
Remember, Knowledge should be enabled. [image]